# snake reinfocement learning does not learn

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I’m new to reinf learning, and I’m trying this code, but the snake always goes right without learning, I can’t find the bug, could you help me?

THE SNAKE CLASS

```
                      import pygame
                            from random import randint
                            from DQN import DQNAgent
                            import numpy as np
                            from keras.utils import to_categorical
                            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                            import seaborn as sns
                            import numpy as np
                            
                            # Set options to activate or deactivate the game view, and its speed
                            display_option = False
                            speed = 0
                            pygame.font.init()
                            
                            
                            class Game:
                            
                            def __init__(self, game_width, game_height):
                            pygame.display.set_caption('SnakeGen')
                            self.game_width = game_width
                            self.game_height = game_height
                            self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width, game_height+60))
                            self.bg = pygame.image.load("img/background.png")
                            #self.barrierImage = pygame.image.load("img/barrier.png")
                            self.crash = False
                            self.player = Player(self)
                            self.food = Food()
                            self.score = 0
                            #self.barrierPositions = [[100,100], [100,120], [100,140], [100,160], [100,180], [100,200], [100,200], [100,220], [100,240], [100,260], [100,280], [100,300]]
                            #self.barrierPositions = [
                            #   [100,100], [100,120], [100,140], [100,160], [100,180], [100,200], [100,200], [100,220], [100,240], [100,260], [100,280], [100,300]
                            #  ]
                            
                            
                            class Player(object):
                            
                            def __init__(self, game):
                            x = 0.45 * game.game_width
                            y = 0.5 * game.game_height
                            self.x = x - x % 20
                            self.y = y - y % 20
                            self.position = []
                            self.position.append([self.x, self.y])
                            self.food = 1
                            self.eaten = False
                            self.image = pygame.image.load('img/snakeBody.png')
                            self.x_change = 20
                            self.y_change = 0
                            
                            def update_position(self, x, y):
                            if self.position[-1][0] != x or self.position[-1][1] != y:
                            if self.food > 1:
                                for i in range(0, self.food - 1):
                                    self.position[i][0], self.position[i][1] = self.position[i + 1]
                            self.position[-1][0] = x
                            self.position[-1][1] = y
                            
                            def do_move(self, move, x, y, game, food,agent):
                            move_array = [self.x_change, self.y_change]
                            
                            if self.eaten:
                            
                            self.position.append([self.x, self.y])
                            self.eaten = False
                            self.food = self.food + 1
                            if np.array_equal(move ,[1, 0, 0]):
                            move_array = self.x_change, self.y_change
                            elif np.array_equal(move,[0, 1, 0]) and self.y_change == 0:  # right - going horizontal
                            move_array = [0, self.x_change]
                            elif np.array_equal(move,[0, 1, 0]) and self.x_change == 0:  # right - going vertical
                            move_array = [-self.y_change, 0]
                            elif np.array_equal(move, [0, 0, 1]) and self.y_change == 0:  # left - going horizontal
                            move_array = [0, -self.x_change]
                            elif np.array_equal(move,[0, 0, 1]) and self.x_change == 0:  # left - going vertical
                            move_array = [self.y_change, 0]
                            self.x_change, self.y_change = move_array
                            self.x = x + self.x_change
                            self.y = y + self.y_change
                            
                            if self.x < 20 or self.x > game.game_width-40 or self.y < 20 or self.y > game.game_height-40 or [self.x, self.y] in self.position:# or [self.x, self.y] in game.barrierPositions:
                            game.crash = True
                            eat(self, food, game)
                            
                            self.update_position(self.x, self.y)
                            
                            def display_player(self, x, y, food, game):
                            self.position[-1][0] = x
                            self.position[-1][1] = y
                            
                            if game.crash == False:
                            for i in range(food):
                                x_temp, y_temp = self.position[len(self.position) - 1 - i]
                                game.gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (x_temp, y_temp))
                            
                            update_screen()
                            else:
                            pygame.time.wait(300)
                            
                            
                            class Food(object):
                            
                            def __init__(self):
                            self.x_food = 240
                            self.y_food = 200
                            self.image = pygame.image.load('img/food2.png')
                            
                            def food_coord(self, game, player):
                            x_rand = randint(20, game.game_width - 40)
                            self.x_food = x_rand - x_rand % 20
                            y_rand = randint(20, game.game_height - 40)
                            self.y_food = y_rand - y_rand % 20
                            if [self.x_food, self.y_food] not in player.position :#and [self.x_food, self.y_food] not in game.barrierPositions:
                            return self.x_food, self.y_food
                            else:
                            self.food_coord(game,player)
                            
                            def display_food(self, x, y, game):
                            game.gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (x, y))
                            update_screen()
                            
                            
                            def eat(player, food, game):
                            if player.x == food.x_food and player.y == food.y_food:
                            food.food_coord(game, player)
                            player.eaten = True
                            game.score = game.score + 1
                            
                            
                            def get_record(score, record):
                            if score >= record:
                            return score
                            else:
                            return record
                            
                            
                            def display_ui(game, score, record):
                            myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Segoe UI', 20)
                            myfont_bold = pygame.font.SysFont('Segoe UI', 20, True)
                            text_score = myfont.render('SCORE: ', True, (0, 0, 0))
                            text_score_number = myfont.render(str(score), True, (0, 0, 0))
                            text_highest = myfont.render('HIGHEST SCORE: ', True, (0, 0, 0))
                            text_highest_number = myfont_bold.render(str(record), True, (0, 0, 0))
                            game.gameDisplay.blit(text_score, (45, 440))
                            game.gameDisplay.blit(text_score_number, (120, 440))
                            game.gameDisplay.blit(text_highest, (190, 440))
                            game.gameDisplay.blit(text_highest_number, (350, 440))
                            game.gameDisplay.blit(game.bg, (10, 10))
                            
                            #for coord in game.barrierPositions:
                            #    game.gameDisplay.blit(game.barrierImage, (coord[0], coord[1]))
                            
                            
                            def display(player, food, game, record):
                            game.gameDisplay.fill((255, 255, 255))
                            display_ui(game, game.score, record)
                            player.display_player(player.position[-1][0], player.position[-1][1], player.food, game)
                            food.display_food(food.x_food, food.y_food, game)
                            
                            
                            def update_screen():
                            pygame.display.update()
                            pygame.event.get()
                            
                            
                            def initialize_game(player, game, food, agent):
                            state_init1 = agent.get_state(game, player, food)  # [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
                            action = [1, 0, 0]
                            player.do_move(action, player.x, player.y, game, food, agent)
                            state_init2 = agent.get_state(game, player, food)
                            reward1 = agent.set_reward(player, game.crash)
                            agent.remember(state_init1, action, reward1, state_init2, game.crash)
                            agent.replay_new(agent.memory)
                            
                            
                            def plot_seaborn(array_counter, array_score):
                            sns.set(color_codes=True)
                            ax = sns.regplot(np.array([array_counter])[0], np.array([array_score])[0], color="b", x_jitter=.1, line_kws={'color':'green'})
                            ax.set(xlabel='games', ylabel='score')
                            plt.show()
                            
                            def run():
                            global display_option
                            global speed
                            pygame.init()
                            agent = DQNAgent()
                            counter_games = 0
                            score_plot = []
                            counter_plot =[]
                            record = 0
                            num_games = 10
                            while counter_games < num_games:
                            
                            if counter_games > num_games - 40 and not display_option:
                             display_option = True
                             speed = 25
                            
                            # Initialize classes
                            game = Game(440, 440)
                            player1 = game.player
                            food1 = game.food
                            
                            # Perform first move
                            initialize_game(player1, game, food1, agent)
                            
                            if display_option:
                            display(player1, food1, game, record)
                            
                            while not game.crash:
                            #agent.epsilon is set to give randomness to actions
                            agent.epsilon = 80 - counter_games
                            
                            #get old state
                            state_old = agent.get_state(game, player1, food1)
                            
                            #perform random actions based on agent.epsilon, or choose the action
                            if randint(0, 200) < agent.epsilon:
                                final_move = to_categorical(randint(0, 2), num_classes=3)
                            else:
                                # predict action based on the old state
                                prediction = agent.model.predict(state_old.reshape((1,11)))
                                final_move = to_categorical(np.argmax(prediction[0]), num_classes=3)
                                
                            #perform new move and get new state
                            player1.do_move(final_move, player1.x, player1.y, game, food1, agent)
                            state_new = agent.get_state(game, player1, food1)
                            
                            #set treward for the new state
                            reward = agent.set_reward(player1, game.crash)
                            
                            #train short memory base on the new action and state
                            agent.train_short_memory(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, game.crash)
                            
                            # store the new data into a long term memory
                            agent.remember(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, game.crash)
                            record = get_record(game.score, record)
                            if display_option:
                                display(player1, food1, game, record)
                                pygame.time.wait(speed)
                            
                            agent.replay_new(agent.memory)
                            counter_games += 1
                            print('Game', counter_games, '      Score:', game.score)
                            score_plot.append(game.score)
                            counter_plot.append(counter_games)
                            agent.model.save_weights('weights.hdf5')
                            plot_seaborn(counter_plot, score_plot)
                            
                            
                            run()
```

DQN CLASS

```
                            from keras.optimizers import Adam
                            from keras.models import Sequential
                            from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout
                            import random
                            import numpy as np
                            import pandas as pd
                            from operator import add
                            
                            
                            class DQNAgent(object):
                            
                            def __init__(self):
                            self.reward = 0
                            self.gamma = 0.9
                            self.dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
                            self.short_memory = np.array([])
                            self.agent_target = 1
                            self.agent_predict = 0
                            self.learning_rate = 0.0005
                            #self.model = self.network()
                            self.model = self.network("weights.hdf5")
                            self.epsilon = 0
                            self.actual = []
                            self.memory = []
                            
                            def get_state(self, game, player, food):
                            
                            state = [
                            (player.x_change == 20 and player.y_change == 0 and (
                                    (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [20, 0])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][0] + 20 >= (game.game_width - 20)# or
                                    #(list(map(add, player.position[-1], [20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == -20 and player.y_change == 0 and (
                                    (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [-20, 0])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][0] - 20 < 20 #or
                                   # (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [-20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == 0 and player.y_change == -20 and (
                                    (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, -20])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][-1] - 20 < 20 #or
                                    #(list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, -20])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == 0 and player.y_change == 20 and (
                                    (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, 20])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][-1] + 20 >= (game.game_height-20)# or
                                    #(list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, 20])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )),  # danger straight
                            
                            (player.x_change == 0 and player.y_change == -20 and (
                                    (list(map(add,player.position[-1],[20, 0])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[ -1][0] + 20 > (game.game_width-20) #or
                                    #(list(map(add, player.position[-1], [20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == 0 and player.y_change == 20 and (
                                    (list(map(add,player.position[-1], [-20,0])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][0] - 20 < 20 or
                                    (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [-20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == -20 and player.y_change == 0 and (
                                    (list(map(add ,player.position[-1],[0,-20])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][-1] - 20 < 20# or
                                # (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, -20])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == 20 and player.y_change == 0 and (
                                    (list(map(add,player.position[-1],[0,20])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][-1] + 20 >= (game.game_height-20) #or
                                # (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [-20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )),  # danger right
                            
                            (player.x_change == 0 and player.y_change == 20 and (
                                    (list(map(add,player.position[-1],[20,0])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][0] + 20 > (game.game_width-20) #or
                                # (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == 0 and player.y_change == -20 and (
                                    (list(map(add, player.position[-1],[-20,0])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][0] - 20 < 20 #or
                                #  (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [-20, 0])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == 20 and player.y_change == 0 and (
                                    (list(map(add,player.position[-1],[0,-20])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][-1] - 20 < 20 #or
                                #  (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, -20])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )) or
                            (player.x_change == -20 and player.y_change == 0 and (
                                    (list(map(add,player.position[-1],[0,20])) in player.position) or
                                    player.position[-1][-1] + 20 >= (game.game_height-20) #or
                                #  (list(map(add, player.position[-1], [0, 20])) in game.barrierPositions)
                            )), #danger left
                            
                            
                            player.x_change == -20,  # move left
                            player.x_change == 20,  # move right
                            player.y_change == -20,  # move up
                            player.y_change == 20,  # move down
                            food.x_food < player.x,  # food left
                            food.x_food > player.x,  # food right
                            food.y_food < player.y,  # food up
                            food.y_food > player.y  # food down
                            ]
                            
                            for i in range(len(state)):
                            if state[i]:
                                state[i]=1
                            else:
                                state[i]=0
                            
                            return np.asarray(state)
                            
                            def set_reward(self, player, crash):
                            self.reward = 0
                            if crash:
                            self.reward = -10
                            return self.reward
                            if player.eaten:
                            self.reward = 10
                            return self.reward
                            
                            def network(self, weights=None):
                            model = Sequential()
                            model.add(Dense(units=120, activation='relu', input_dim=11))
                            model.add(Dropout(0.15))
                            model.add(Dense(units=120, activation='relu'))
                            model.add(Dropout(0.15))
                            model.add(Dense(units=120, activation='relu'))
                            model.add(Dropout(0.15))
                            model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
                            opt = Adam(self.learning_rate)
                            model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
                            
                            if weights:
                            model.load_weights(weights)
                            return model
                            
                            def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
                            self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
                            
                            def replay_new(self, memory):
                            if len(memory) > 1000:
                            minibatch = random.sample(memory, 1000)
                            else:
                            minibatch = memory
                            for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
                            target = reward
                            if not done:
                                target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(np.array([next_state]))[0])
                            target_f = self.model.predict(np.array([state]))
                            target_f[0][np.argmax(action)] = target
                            self.model.fit(np.array([state]), target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
                            
                            def train_short_memory(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
                            target = reward
                            if not done:
                            target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state.reshape((1, 11)))[0])
                            target_f = self.model.predict(state.reshape((1, 11)))
                            target_f[0][np.argmax(action)] = target
                            self.model.fit(state.reshape((1, 11)), target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

Comment: Some advice: 1) Don't implement deep RL algorithms yourself, but use standard implementations, because it is very difficult to get it right; 2) Use a "random" agent to set a baseline against what to compare to; 3) Do not expect that random people on the internet devote their time debugging your code if you don't show you already spent a lot of effort on it.

Comment: thank you for advice